# HighCharts WorlMap datalabel translation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I have one WorldMap by HighCharts in one application. I need to translate my country labels to Portuguese but I can't find a way to do it.
I'm feeding my world chart with the following:

```
 series: [
            {
                data: myDataSeries,
                name: 'Projects',
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: '#BADA55'
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            }
        ]
```

It's possible to change the dataLabels language? I can't find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts doesn't provide the language customization, so it needs to be done manually.

`datalabels.formatter` is a good place to perform translation:

```
function translate(englishName) {
  if (englishName === "Russia") {
    return "Rosja"; // translated 
  }
  return englishName;
}

(...)

      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return translate(this.point.name);
        }
      }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/m6vaume1/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.dataLabels.formatter